# How to adjust PDPageContentStream offset based on page rotation angle?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

We have text field coordinates to be printed with page rotation 0, but the page on which it has to be printed has rotation of 270 so to adjust the coordinate applied transformation

```
contentStream.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(270), 0, page.getMediaBox().getHeight()));
```

How can we derive general formula for any page rotation angle to adjust the coordinates?

Comment: What *kind of coordinate system* do you want after rotation? For just the rotation you merely need the `Matrix.getRotateInstance` for the angle, nothing else required. The additional two values merely constitute an additional shift.

Comment: After rotation I want coordinate system with (0,0) on left bottom corner same as with page rotation 0 degree. Like in example above with 270, I had to adjust y

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"general formula for any page rotation angle"*? I mean, there are three interesting cases, 90°, 180°, and 270°, so the simplest approach would be to show the values for these three cases. Making that a single generic formula would probably create something much more obfuscated.

Comment: Yes, handled for 3 cases. I am worried for angles other than these 3

Comment: Well, for other angles there might not be a well-defined "left bottom corner"...

Comment: The page rotation (`setRotation()`) is always a multiple of 90.